# sql server insert into dynamic global named table from from xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-insert

I would like to insert data into temp global table with dynamic named:

```
SET @SQL = '
CREATE TABLE '+Cast(@TableName as VARCHAR(60))+'
(
    Adr VARCHAR(1000)
)';
execute (@SQL);
```

I'm able to retreive values which I need like:

```
SELECT Recipient.query('.').value('.','varchar(15)')
FROM   @not.nodes('Data/MgRec' ) xmlData(ref) CROSS APPLY
    ref.nodes('Recipient') AS Recipients(Recipient) ;
```

Which give me list with some values..
Now when I'd like to insert those values:

```
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO '+ Cast(@TableName as VARCHAR(60))+' (Adr) 
 Select Recipient.query(''.'').value(''.'',''varchar(15)'')
FROM  '+ Cast(@not as VARCHAR(60))  +'.nodes(''Data/MgRec'' ) xmlData(ref) CROSS APPLY
    ref.nodes(''Recipient'') AS Recipients(Recipient)' ;
    execute (@SQL);
SET @SQL = 'select * from ' +Cast(@TableName as VARCHAR(60))
execute (@SQL);
```

And here I'm stucked , error:

> Target string size is too small to represent the XML instance

Any advice, please?

Bellow @not xml:

```
<Data>
  <MgRec>
    <Recipient>10800234</Recipient>
    <Recipient>24900005</Recipient>
    <Recipient>24900004</Recipient>
    <Recipient>10201026</Recipient>
    <Recipient>66600019</Recipient>
    <Recipient>14042243</Recipient>
  </MgRec>
</Data>
```

Comment: You only need one `.nodes` like this `.nodes('Data/MgRec/Recipient')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just properly parametrise your query?

```sql
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo',
        @TableName sysname = N'YourTable';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = '
CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)+ N'
(
    Adr VARCHAR(1000)
)
INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)+ N' (Adr)
SELECT Recipient.value(''(./text())[1]'',''varchar(15)'')
FROM @not.nodes(''Data/MgRec'' ) xmlData(ref)
     CROSS APPLY ref.nodes(''Recipient'') AS Recipients(Recipient) ;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@not xml', @not;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c38fc9fcc9945c1b75daf544092080ef)

Comment: Thank you for replay. With your solution is another error: Procedure sys.sp_executesql, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: It *is* an `nvarchar` in the above, @zawier ... *"DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);"* The error is telling you the problem there; you haven't copied my code properly

Comment: you right :) nvarchar not varchar ;)  but still I have got null values

Comment: Now I have sample XML, fixed @zawier .