# SQL server - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Simple query:

```
SET @SQL='(SELECT Adr from '+Cast(@TableName as VARCHAR(60)) +' FOR XML PATH (''Not'') , TYPE)';
EXEC (@SQL)
```

returns error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Anyone know why? Or how to fix it?

**Updated query:**

```
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo',
        @TableName sysname = N'[WARNING WARNING, INJECTION ALERT!!!]'; --This solution doesn't suffer from injection any more.
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (''https://www.my.website.'' as ns)  
SELECT 
    Q.A AS [@A],
    Q.B AS [@B],
    Q.C AS [@C],


       D.D AS [@D],
        N.E AS [@E],
        CONVERT(char(10), N.CR, 126) AS [@DN],
CASE WHEN  '+ QUOTENAME(@IsRejected) +' =1 THEN '+ QUOTENAME(@ElementName )+'  END AS  [Rejected/ElementName ],
        ''mess'' AS [TN/@Z],
        @T2 AS [TN/T]
    ,(SELECT * FROM ' +QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +' FOR XML PATH (''Not''),type)
FROM
    [DB].[dbo].[Q] AS Q 
    LEFT JOIN [DB].[dbo].[D] AS D ON Q.Id=D.Id
    LEFT JOIN [DB].[dbo].[N] AS N ON D.DoctId=N.DocId
WHERE 
    Q.Id=@InboxID
FOR XML PATH (''Not'');';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@T2 int, @InboxID int', @T2, @InboxID; --Data types guessed.
```

At upper case query retuns null.  Maybe that way it will be easier to explain .

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement, fix the error there, and propagate.

Comment: Also, fix your injection issue; never inject unsanitised strings into a dynamic statement. Use `QUOTENAME`. Also, converting `@TableName` to a `varchar` doesn't make a lot of sense; objects use `sysname` as the data type. I demonstrated all this in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68471104/2029983) i gave you the other day.

Comment: Hi Larnu :) With print output there is not much changed: (SELECT Adr from ##TEMP_Adr_476914_2021_07_22_13_49_39_343 FOR XML PATH ('Not') , TYPE)

Comment: Note, as well, queries don't go in parenthesis unless they are subqueries. Voting to close as typographical.

Comment: That one is actually cut from bigger query, and yes it's orginally subquery..

Comment: But it's not any more, @zawier . So it doesn't go in parenthesis; and the parenthesis are why you are getting an error.

Comment: Good point. @Larnu. I have updated description where I have included main query which is problematic to me. Right now I'm not able to receive anything.

Comment: ... Why are you injecting parameters again... **Parametrise** your parameters...

Comment: You don't define your variable `@T2` in your dynamic statement.

Comment: Do you _really_ need the global temp table?  I've found it's extremely rare that they are necessary and best to avoid when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, as I stated in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68471104/2029983) I gave you yesterday; **parametrise**:

```sql
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo',
        @TableName sysname = N'[WARNING WARNING, INJECTION ALERT!!!]'; --This solution doesn't suffer from injection any more.
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (''https://www.my.website.'' as ns)  
SELECT 
    Q.A AS [@A],
    Q.B AS [@B],
    Q.C AS [@C],
    D.D AS [@D],
    N.E AS [@E],
    CONVERT(char(10), N.CR, 126) AS [@DN],
    ''mess'' AS [TN/@Z],
    @T2 AS [TN/T]
    ,(SELECT * FROM ' +QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +' FOR XML PATH (''Not''),type)
FROM
    [DB].[dbo].[Q] AS Q 
    LEFT JOIN [DB].[dbo].[D] AS D ON Q.Id=D.Id
    LEFT JOIN [DB].[dbo].[N] AS N ON D.DoctId=N.DocId
WHERE 
    Q.Id=@InboxID
FOR XML PATH (''Not'');';

--PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@T2 int, @InboxID int', @T2, @InboxID; --Data types guessed.
```

Comment: As always your solutions works great @Larnu. Thank you ! But I have compicated a little bit query and have added  CASE condition. Looks ok but because of it all query again became null.  ElementName is varchar and IsRejected is a BIT.

Comment: If you are getting `NULL` one of the values you are concatenating has the value `NULL`, @zawier .

Comment: IsRejected always contains 0 or 1. ElementName  could be null

Comment: Then when `ElementName` is `NULL` the entire query will have the value `NULL`, @zawier , and no statement will be run. Also, so you *really* have a columns in your table with the names `0` and `1`? I would suggest a better name; those aren't descriptive.

Comment: Oh no @Larnu 0 and 1 are values not names of columns ;) And you are right. Already have tested approach with making ElementName not null and that really caused a issue. Thank you. You are a legend!

Comment: Then whjy are you injecting them @zawier .... From this very answer: ***parametrise:***... Stop making the same mistakes over and over and over. *Parametrise* your **parameters**. The only thin you should be injecting is your object names, and those need to be injected **safely**.